# How to create a new div onclick using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, wordpress

I'm working on a task I need to display Post Content-Img-Title on click without reload the page.

I've coded Below code:

```
// code for ajax portfolio
jQuery('span#ajax_post_abc a').click(function(){
    var portfolio_post_id= jQuery(this).attr('id');
    var ajaxurl = jQuery('#ajax-script-url').val();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,        
        data: {
            "action": "load-filter2", 
            port_post_id: portfolio_post_id 
        },
        success: function(response) {
            jQuery(".aajax-post-content").html(response); }  
        });
    });

    //New Ajax portfolio div 
    jQuery('#ajax_post_abc').click(function() {
        jQuery(this).addClass('aajax-post-content');
    });
```

And the resultant response in will be displayed in `aajax-post-content` div.
But the problem is if I have `n` posts and I click on `n+1`, `n+2` and so on it does not shows the output. But if I click on the very first Post `n0` then it will show the output as I need.

Comment: use append() instead of html [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Answer (score 2):

```
content.append('<div class="item"><span>' +data + '</span></div>');
```

Comment: @vibz you can reffer this post

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321748/jquery-add-new-div-onclick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321748/jquery-add-new-div-onclick)

Answer (score 0):

Your code will only show the most recent change which happened.

If you want to see each change you must append the changes and use .append instead of .html

for example:

```
jQuery(".aajax-post-content").append(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery.html() replaces the inner html of the item. jQuery.append() adds a new element as a child to the specified container.

Sounds like you need append()

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jQuery('span#ajax_post_abc a').click(function(){
    var portfolio_post_id= jQuery(this).attr('id');
    var ajaxurl = jQuery('#ajax-script-url').val();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,        
        data: {
            "action": "load-filter2", 
            port_post_id: portfolio_post_id 
        },
        success: function(response) {
            jQuery(".aajax-post-content").html(response);
            jQuery(#ajax_post_abc).addClass('aajax-post-content');
             }  
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `#content` with any selector you want.

```
$('<div>new content</div>').appendTo($('#content'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use On method instead of Click function because when multiple clicks are to be included,it never works,So Change your code as

$(document).on( 'click','#ajax_post_abc', function (e) {
    jQuery(this).addClass('aajax-post-content');
});
```

Thank You Vibz...